# Catmull-Clark Subdivision Surface is causing artifacts on a circular mesh

Tags: modeling

How to deal with this mess to make this mesh smooth. I was using circle to make it

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39326/modeling-a-bullet/39330#39330

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The subdivision modifier won't produce *good* results with triangles in the geometry. (Carlo mentioned [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39330/30849), which showcases how the modifier works on topology.)

To solve this, use quads only.

[image]

1. Delete the center vertice, select the edge loop and do the **Grid Fill** operation.
   [image]
2. Recreate the sperical shape. Set the Cursor as Pivot (<kbd>.</kbd>). Place it in the imaginary center of the spherical shape. Select the flat grid geometry and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale to sphere.
   [image]